# Lebesgue decomposition of a family of measures

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

I'am asking myself the following: let $\lambda$ be a positive $\sigma$-finite measure on $\mathbb{R}$ and $(\mu_t)_{t \in \mathbb{R}}$ a family of probability measures on $\mathbb{R}$ with the proberty: $t\mapsto \mu_t(A)$ is measurable for all Borel subsets $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$.

Furthermore, let $\mu_t=\mu_t^a+\mu_t^s$ be the Lebesgue decompositions with respect to $\lambda$, i.e. $\mu_t^a$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $\lambda$ and $\mu_t^s,\lambda$ are mutually singular to each other.

Is it true that also $t\mapsto \mu_t^s(A)$ and $t\mapsto \mu_t^a(A)$ are measurable functions?

I can't find any proof or counterexample...

Best regards,
Selanox